# snap.svg drag "real" position

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I want to drag a line to the element which I drag. for this I need the "real" position of the element while dragging.

I tried this:

```
textSign.drag(function (dx, dy, posx, posy) {
    var myMatrix = new Snap.Matrix();
    myMatrix.translate(dx,dy); 
    this.transform(myMatrix.toTransformString());

    //drag another element

}, function(x,y,event){
    //contains only mouse position
}, function(){
    this.attr({x: parseFloat(this.attr("x")) + this.matrix.e, y: parseFloat(this.attr("y")) + this.matrix.f});
    this.transform('t0,0');
});
```

Can I get the real position (of the matrix or sth) while moving?

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are quite trying to do with your dragging, and why you are using a matrix, could you put what you have on a fiddle, then it may be a bit more obvious ?

Comment: i want to set the end of the point(x2,y2) to the center of my object, while dragging: http://jsbin.com/koheyekema/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by grabbing the bounding box of the element being moved, and then change the attribute to that.

So the additional code would be...

```
  var bb = this.getBBox();
  line.attr({ x2: bb.cx, y2: bb.cy })
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dawazesabo/2/edit)

You can also get rid of the matrix stuff...

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/suramaleju/1/edit?html,js,output)